# Javascript or Jquery Event Trigger - How to trigger an event when a value is passed by javascript to an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger an event when a value is passed by javascript to an input box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

document.getElementById("myInput").value = 100;

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the value 100 auto generated, "You Wrote 100" should be displayed

Comment: Note that I found that duplicate by searching on your title; it was the second result. [Please do some research before asking on Stack Overflow](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Noted. I will make sure to research more in the future. Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know you problem, it's working fine here. JS example:

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").value = 100;

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<p id="demo">You wrote: 100</p>
```

jQuery example:

```js
$('#myInput').val(100);

$('#myInput').keyup(function(){
  $('#demo').html('You wrote: ' + $('#myInput').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput">

<p id="demo">You wrote: 100</p>
```

I would recommend you to use onkeyup because it's more dynamic than onchange.